# Order of logical decoding output on Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Given the following table in PostgreSQL 11.1, what is the order of logical decoding output rows?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  t1_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  ,name TEXT
)
;
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  t2_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  ,t1_id INTEGER NOT NULL
  ,name TEXT
  ,CONSTRAINT fkt2_t1id FOREIGN KEY (t1_id)
    REFERENCES t1 (t1_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
;
CREATE TABLE t3 (
  t3_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  ,t2_id INTEGER NOT NULL
  ,name TEXT
  ,CONSTRAINT fkt3_t2id FOREIGN KEY (t2_id)
    REFERENCES t2 (t2_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
;
```

Because of `DEFERRABLE` foreign key, in one transaction, a referencing row `(t3, t2)` can be inserted before the referenced rows `(t2, t1)`.

```
BEGIN
;
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES
(1, 1, '3')
;
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
(1, 1, '2')
;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1, '1')
;
COMMIT;
```

### Question

What is the order of logical decoding output ?

1. Referenced rows first, then referencing rows.
   t1 → t2 → t3
2. Same order as statements.
   t3 → t2 → t1
3. Non-deterministic order

I guess No.1 is the answer. But I want to confirm whether postgresql guarantees such order or not, with/without DEFERRABLE constraint condition.

Comment: Should be 2, nothing else would make sense

Comment: Ummm... logical decoding depends on WAL. You may be right.